# OutofmemoryError when create bitmap

Tags: android

I wrote this in `onBindViewHolder` of `RecycleViewAdapter`,

> Bitmap.createBitmap( 240, 420, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);

And I got OutofmemoryError when scrolling my RecycleView. 
Down size of image is not good solution because error will happen when memory not enough.

Please help, thanks.

Comment: why do you need to createBitmap in onBindViewHolder ?

Comment: I have come across this issue couple of time and resolved using following link
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ofcourse it gives you **OutOfMemory** Exception.

Do you know how many times does your adapter call the onBind method?

A LOT. And you create a bitmap every time. You don't reuse it, you don't recycle it, you create it over and over again.

What do you use that Bitmap for more exactly? Maybe you don't even need to create it every time.

You should use a cache mechanism, you can use a library to display the Bitmap (like Universal Image Loader, Glide, Picasso, Volley, Lazy loading).

Comment: Thanks DDsix, but I need difference size, color bitmap in each item of list. I try with create one bitmap, resize and change color when call onBindViewHolder but performance of list is very bad.

Comment: So you only need to display a colored square of different sizes on every row? There are other ways of doing this. Bitmaps are not very efficient, you know

Comment: I need a bitmap to make input for asynctask, it must be a bitmap here. Trust is I must call this 'mImageFetcher.setLoadingImage(Bitmap)' once in constructor of adapter, but each image view in adapter, I have difference loading type (bitmap).

Comment: I just wanted to help you and get you to think outside the box. If you "MUST" use a bitmap, then I invite you to it. Good luck getting rid of that OutOfMemory excpetion, though.

Comment: In software, there is always another way :)